# Segmentation and Paging hardware

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

The below figure illustrates the hardware implementation of segmentation :

[image]

The hardware implementation of paging is also shown below :

[image]

Source: Operating system concepts textbook
As we can see that both memory schemes use offsets in their logical address definition. In segmentation, we always check that this offset is less than the limit ( size ) of the segment, if the offset is larger than the limit of the segment, then we trap to the operating system ( addressing error ). However, this check is not available in paging hardware, although it also uses offset in its physical address?  Why is that ? Does this mean that in paging we always guarantee that no "unauthorized" memory access can be made ( for example memory access to another process's address space ) ?

Comment: x86-64 doesn't use segmentation anymore. As for unauthorized memory access, each process has its own set of page tables so they shouldn't be able to access any other process's address space.

Comment: @wxz Thanks a lot. We can apply the same concept in segmentation, where every process has its segment table, so why still do we check that the offset < limit in segmentation? Also in paging, there is a possibility that a wrong offset can be addressed that is longer than the page size, so why we don't do the same check in paging ?

Comment: See [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html). The number of offset bits is determined by `PAGE_SHIFT`, which for [x86](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/page_types.h#L10) is defined as 12. This means the offset allows us to access all 4096 bytes (2^12) in the page we're looking for. With that offset, you can't address outside that page.

Comment: @wxz Ok, I got it but under one condition is that the page size is always a constant, not a variable. So this means that in X86 the page size is 4K bytes according to your example, is that right?

Comment: That's the default for x86 (4k bytes = 1 page). If you use Hugepages then your page size could be different. It's not a variable in the sense that it won't change during runtime, you'd have to recompile your kernel and reboot.